# solaris + why cant ping to default getway

Tags: linux, ssh, solaris, ping

I have Solaris machine with IP 10.10.10.100 and default getway 10.10.10.1 and subnet 255.255.255.0

remark - solaris machine connected to cisco switch via cross cable and from switch to my laptop

I configure my laptop to connect to my Solaris machine
so my laptop IP is 10.10.10.1 and subnet 255.255.255.0

but something not clearly

I have ssh connection  from my laptop to my Solaris machine ( I mean I in my solaris machine )

but from Solaris machine I can do ping to 10.10.10.1 ? ( how it can be ??? )

please advice why?

Comment: Typically, assigning your laptop the same IP address as the gateway is a Very Bad Thing. Beyond that, I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: if you are just using a xover cable then use 10.10.10.101 for the laptop don't set a gateway

Comment: but I solaris machine need ping to 10.10.10.1 (its because some requirment from app)

Comment: Tell us more about what you're doing -- Are you using a crossover cable? Connecting through a switch/hub/your office netowrk? Are you using a /24 subnet or something else? (If you're using a /24 these two IPs are on the same subnet. The gateway doesn't enter in to it).

Comment: I use LAN cable from my laptop to swith and from switch LAN cable to solaris machine (see also update about netmask)

Comment: please tell me this is not on a production network, right?

Comment: what you mean production network?

Comment: is this a school project?

Comment: no , why you think this is school project , this is LAB system

Comment: ok same basic idea was just curious, and what would be the app that requires "(its because some requirment from app)" ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, it's not actually clear what you're trying to accomplish.

When you already have a gateway with an IP 10.10.10.1 and you plug in another machine (your laptop) and give it an IP of 10.10.10.1, Very Bad Things will happen to your network.

The Solaris machine is now confused as to which machine it is supposed to talk to on the LAN.  If you tell it to ping 10.10.10.1, you may get the new machine or you may get the gateway.

Your first priority would be to change the IP address of the laptop to something other than 10.10.10.1.  Is there a DHCP server on the network?  Then tell the laptop to dynamically obtain the IP address.  If there isn't a DHCP server, then give it an IP that's not being used by any other machine.

Once that's straightened out, flush the arp table on the Solaris machine, and try again with whatever test you're trying to do.